# three.js: switch from simple material to multi- on runtime

Tags: javascript, three.js

r65

Hello,

I need to switch from simple material to multi-material on runtime. But can't. May be I miss something obvious?

My test code is below (jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/plotnik/8RtTy/3/). Simple material is assigned to object initially, multi-material is assigned after the render() call to simulate runtime substitution.

```
var geom = new THREE.CubeGeometry(1, 1, 1);

var materialSimple = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x020202});

// 6-color 
var materialMulti = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial([
    new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 }),
    new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xffff00 }),
    new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xffffff }),
    new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0x00ffff }),
    new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0x0000ff }),
    new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0x000000 })
    ]);

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, materialSimple);

scene.add(mesh);

var render = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);

    mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
    mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

render();

// switch to multi-material
mesh.material = materialMulti;
mesh.material.needsUpdate = true;
```

The code doesn't work as I expect. The result looks like only materialMulti[0] (of red color) is assigned to the whole mesh.

I will be grateful for the assistance.

Comment: Is this approach satisfactory for your use case? http://jsfiddle.net/8RtTy/4/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/abadabanades/8RtTy/15/

I updated the fiddle, so that the materials change after 4 seconds, alerting the users (It was hard for me to see the change)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switching materials at runtime can be tricky with WebGLRenderer. You can read more about it in the Wiki article [How to Update Things with WebGLRenderer](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/introduction/How-to-update-things).

In you case, you can just use `MeshFaceMaterial` all the time, and achieve the effect you want by changing only the material colors.

EDIT: `MeshFaceMaterial` has been deprecated. You can now pass in an array of materials directly to the `Mesh` constructor`like so:

```
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, materials_array );
```

three.js r.91

Comment: I've seen your previous comment and answered on Jan 17. Thank you for additional explanations. "How to update..." is my favorite reading. Let me ask: why Three.js authors don't hide some update details in wrappers like setMaterial() and similar? It could make documentation shorter, migration from release to release smoother etc.

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example?

Comment: Sorry for my  snail postings. I meant approximately the following. For example, Mesh.setMaterial() could compare new and already assigned materials, set .needsUpdate in accordance with current release rules, signal errors.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the correct forum for a design discussion. Study the three.js source code, and if you have a suggestion for improvement, you can post a pull request on the three.js github board.